# Download Gmail emails via HTTP

Tags: email, gmail, firewall, imap, pop3

On my local university the public internet connection has POP and IMAP filtered; only HTTP and HTTPS are allowed. I'd like to use Thunderbird (or some other Email client) to download my Gmail emails on my laptop to read them offline.

Does Thunderbird (or other Email client) support downloading GMail e-mails via HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some [http tunnel](http://www.google.com/?q=HTTP%20Tunnel) to get through the university's firewall. If you've got access to some server, this should be easy.

HTTP tunneling may be disallowed, check the policies first!

Comment: HTTP tunnel is allowed.

Comment: So just choose some solution, their are both commercial (services where you don't need an own server) and open source tools (requiring you've got access to a server which allows you to install software) which are able to tunnel traffic through HTTP.